# disabling multiple space in text area javascript

Tags: javascript

To avoid typing multiple spaces in text area I'm calling a function on `onCLick`, on keyup and written the code below

```
var val = document.getelemntByID('trmp');
val.value = val .value.replace(/ +(?= )/g,'');
```

this is working fine in Firefox, in IE7 it's working, but causing some other problem, like select a word and delete it will delete entire text area content

Comment: Can you produce a jsfiddle.net and tell us what to do in which browser to recreate the problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4G8Lr/14/ -> first time im using tht editor im nt getting correctly

Comment: apparently your RegExp does not match anything: http://jsfiddle.net/4G8Lr/29/ Try any other value (`/ /`) and it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the regex only for space.Add a keycode condition.

Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hikki/FNJmE/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to rewrite value of textarea all the time because it potentially can be buggy. Just disable input space if previous char is space:

```
$(function(){
    var $tA=$('#temp');
    $tA.keydown(function(e){
        var cursorPos = getCursorPosition($tA.get(0));
        if(e.which === 32 && cursorPos > 0 && $tA.val()[cursorPos-1] === ' '){
           return false;            
        }
    });
});

getCursorPosition = function(el) {
        var pos = 0;
        // IE Support
        if (document.selection) {
            el.focus();
            var Sel = document.selection.createRange();
            var SelLength = document.selection.createRange().text.length;
            Sel.moveStart('character', -el.value.length);
            pos = Sel.text.length - SelLength;
        }
        // Firefox support
        else if (el.selectionStart || el.selectionStart == '0')
            pos = el.selectionStart;

        return pos;
    }
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/y6unN/2/